# docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345

Tags: osx, python, docker

I have downloaded the anaconda docker image from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda/) and I am running it on MacOS.
I have come across the following issue and I would highly appreciate your help!

When I try running Ipython by the following command

```
docker run -it pyimg ipython
```

I get the error

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"ipython\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

This makes me think that the $PATH in docker does not entail the location of ipython. 
However, when I spin the container by first executing the bash and then by launching ipython, everything works fine!
More precisely,

```
docker run -it pyimg bash
```

and then

```
ipython
```

works fine..

To make things even more confusing,

```
docker run -it pyimg python
```

works perfectly!
I already checked inside the container and realized that both python as well as ipython are located in the same directory **/opt/conda/bin**

How is it possible that this behavior is exhibited and how can I fix it?
Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Executing:

```
docker run -it pyimg ipython
```

Implies you have `iphython` installed on your host OS. That is, on your MacOS as you stated. If `iphython` is installed, run it with `privileged` switch:

```
docker run -it --privileged pyimg ipython
```